# Firefox Refuses IIS Express Certificate with error "SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE"

Tags: firefox, certificate, iis

I have IIS Express running a .Net Core web application.

Chrome is able to browse the HTTPS version fine, and until recently so was Firefox. Suddenly I'm getting this error:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to localhost:44358. Certificate
>   key usage inadequate for attempted operation. Error code:
>   SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE

And unlike the error for a self-signed certificate, there is no way for me to accept the certificate or "Continue Anyway".

I have tried:

- Regenerating Firefox's certificate store (deleting cert9.db and cert8.db)
- Repairing IISExpress.exe
- Uninstalling and re-installing IISExpress.exe
- Updating Visual Studio (2019)

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio generates its own CA and installs it into the Windows Certificate store for web development. You can configure Firefox to [import CAs from the Windows Certificate Store](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/AddRootToFirefox) by enabling the security.enterprise_roots.enabled (formerly ImportEnterpriseRoots) setting in Firefox.

Do the following to enable use of the Windows Certificate Store by Firefox:

1. Open Firefox
2. Navigate to "about:config"
3. Search for "ImportEnterpriseRoots"
4. Add it, setting it to true
5. Restart Firefox

Comment: This doesn't work (any more), and it is also unclear whether this comes with any risks, and what the error message means in the first place, so anyone considering this solution can make an informed decision.

Comment: @FlorianWinter I think I'm clear enough on what I'm suggesting. If someone trusted a CA  in their OS credential store, then already were warned about the consequences. Thanks for pointing out that Mozilla updated the setting name. I found the new one by following the reference link to their wiki which provides plenty of details for you if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE` error if the website has an HTTPS binding that is configured to use a certificate which no longer exists in the server's certificate store. If you inspect the connection (by clicking the lock icon), you will also see that there is no "View Certificate" button, because there is no certificate. Obviously, this is not something you can fix in Firefox, but a problem on the server side.

The solution is then to change the binding (in IIS or IIS Express) to use a certificate that exists and is valid.